# Add bare git repositories to gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-rake

Today I learnt that [the rake import task for bare git repositories](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/import.html) is soon to be deprecated (and will be removed later). I have not yet understood what I should do instead:

- [The web project import](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/repo_by_url.html) is for a single project, but I need something I can do programmatically (via REST, ssh or alike).
- [The automated import](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/index.html#automate-group-and-project-import) only mentions other vendors (like GitHub, BitBucket etc.), but I have bare git repositories, which are not on any git server.

So how do import a large number of bare git repositories into GitLab (self-managed)?

Comment: "Today I learned that [link] is soon to be deprecated". I wonder if you could say what [link] is so that we don't have to go to an external website?

Comment: _"I have bare git repositories, which are not on any git server"_ - add them a remote as you have a gitlab server and it is a remote (or you want it to become one of the bares). Then push, this is how git works (and Gitlab bascially, yes you know that better than me). Apart from that, check the first reference you give and there is "To import bare repositories into a GitLab instance:" which might be insightful.

Comment: @hakre So what do you suggest to do? The same as the answer of Arty-chan? Or something different?

Comment: If you have access to the gitlab instance it is perhaps easier to rsync the bare repositories there-in, or clone them into a mounted folder structure, but sure if you feel better with git push like arty-chan suggestes, why not? At the end of the day you decide how you would like to do it. Make yourself a plan. than make yourself a test. Than do a first iteration with a single repository. Automate all the things and let run.

Comment: @hakre This is not really precise, and therefore it does not really help me.

Comment: Okay, perhaps then if you elaborate a _little_ more what you're concerned about that needs more precision I may be able to offer more/better help. Just one more hint beforehand: If you create yourself a little test with a single repository (it sounds you have quite some at hand), you can easily check the procedure yourself. Then extrapolating for many repositories should not be an issue. And in case it was unclear, I think the answer given by Arty-chan outlines a way you can go (in the sense of what works) so if you go with it and it works, this looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting that it doesn't mention it as part of the deprecation notice, but you could write a simple script that loops through all your repositories and creates the project through `git push`.

If you take a look at the [Create a new project with Git push](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/#create-a-new-project-with-git-push) documentation, that should cover the use case you've described.

If you need to create the projects in different namespaces and those don't exist, then you'll need to [create a group via API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html#new-group) as part of your script.